# Django filter and select date only from datetime

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime, django-views

Here is my code on clicking post button on form

```
new_date = request.POST.get('depart_date')
from datetime import date
c = Schedule.objects.filter(bus_id=request.POST.get('bus'), depart_time__date=date.new_date).count()
print(request, c)
```

In my select query, I want to check depart time of selected bus from datetime field. But on checking this, I need to select date only to filter with new_date. On submitting my form, django error show as follows;

type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'new_date'

Comment: try import datetime and then datetime.datetime.now()

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any thing like `date.new_date` in python. I think what you want is `new_date`.

Like

```
c = Schedule.objects.filter(
        bus_id=request.POST.get('bus'),
        depart_time__date=new_date
    ).count()
```